# NativeScript Angular: form field errors don't style correctly

Tags: angular, forms, validation, nativescript

I have a form on my signup page that I think is set up correctly, it validates properly in the JavaScript but the validation styling is strange in the UI.  I've tried it in different layouts (StackLayouts, GridLayouts, etc.) and none of them seem to have an effect on the form fields themselves.

Here is my code:

```
// HTML
<FlexboxLayout
    [formGroup]="form"
    flexDirection="column"
    class="signup-form">
  <FlexboxLayout
      class="signup-form-row">
    <TextField
        hint="First Name"
        returnKeyType="done"
        autocorrect="false"
        class="text-input half-wide"

        formControlName="first_name">
    </TextField>
    <TextField
        hint="Last Name"
        returnKeyType="done"
        autocorrect="false"
        class="text-input half-wide"
        formControlName="last_name">
    </TextField>
  </FlexboxLayout>

  <FlexboxLayout
      class="signup-form-row">
    <TextField
        hint="Email"
        returnKeyType="done"
        autocorrect="false"
        class="text-input full-wide"
        type="email"
        formControlName="email"
        autocapitalizationType="none">
    </TextField>
  </FlexboxLayout>
</FlexboxLayout>
```

```
// JS

import { FormControl, FormGroup, Validators } from '@angular/forms';

...

let controls = {
  first_name: new FormControl(
    environment.SIGNUP.FIRSTNAME || '',
    [Validators.required]
  ),
  last_name: new FormControl(
    environment.SIGNUP.LASTNAME || '',
    [Validators.required]
  ),
  email: new FormControl(
    environment.SIGNUP.EMAIL || '',
    [Validators.required]
  ),
}
this.form = new FormGroup(controls);
```

```
// SCSS
.signup-form {
    flex-direction: row;
    margin-top: 15;
    width: 100%;

    .signup-form-row {
        flex-direction: row;
        justify-content: space-between;
        padding: 0;
        margin: 0;
        height: 60;
        width: 100%;
    }

    .text-input {
        color: #111111;
        font-size: 17;
        letter-spacing: 0.09;
        font-family: "arbeit-light", "Arbeit-Light";
    }

    .text-input.full-wide {
        width: 100%;
    }

    .text-input.half-wide {
        width: 48%;
    }
}
```

And here is the result.

No errors:

[image: No errors image]

And when the required field is now blank:

[image]

It looks like there should be an error message maybe above the red line but it's blank?

Answer (score 0):

I think you're not displaying any error in HTML .

Comment: I'd mark your answer as correct if you showed me how maybe?